# Is that possible to add time outs against apis in locust?

Tags: locust

from locust import HttpUser, task, between
from locust.contrib.fasthttp import FastHttpUser
import json

class QuickstartUser(HttpUser):

```
connection_timeout = 5.0
network_timeout = 5.0

@task
def client_apis(self):

        self.client.get(f"/get/data", headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get it with an [advanced usage of requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#timeouts)